# Oracle varchar2 to timestamp with time zone

Tags: oracle, timezone, timestamp, varchar2

I'm trying to convert a VARCHAR2 variable which contains a timestamp w/ time zone into a DATE variable. I can convert the timestamp without the time zone but when I add logic for timezone I get "ORA-01821: date format not recognized". Please see code below:

```
    DECLARE
      v_string VARCHAR2(400) := '2011-05-12 19:04:41.032645 +00:00';
      v_date   DATE;
    BEGIN

      SELECT to_timestamp(v_string,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF TZH:TZM')
        INTO v_date
        FROM dual;

    END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/toc.htm):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_string VARCHAR2(400) := '2011-05-12 19:04:41.032645 +00:00';
  3     v_date   DATE;
  4  BEGIN
  5     v_date := to_timestamp_tz(v_string, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: Thanks! I just found that too.